# Tar archive error message

Tags: linux, mac-osx, tar

I am getting following error while archiving the user's homedirectory. 
 (trying to migrate a user from one macbook to other since the user's keys are associated with AWS and other tools)

tar cfv user1.tar --exclude 'user1/downloads' user1

**tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.**

After archiving around 70% getting the above error message.

I've read many documents and tried all the advices but still getting same error.

user1/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/Japanese.strings
user1/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/ar.strings
user1/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/French.strings
**tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.**
  user1-MacBook-Pro:Users user1$

Comment: add -v http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/tar-1.12/html_node/tar_16.html to see where the issue is

Comment: -v already running in verbose mode.

Comment: why not just archive the folders one by one.. This itunes things, is the music folder which you can backup separately

Comment: I've tried exclude on "Music" folder later I got issues on Picture folder and excluded that one as well. Now I am getting same error at id_rsa file. I can't exclude that file. Because my ultimate goal is to get those files along with the user account. I strongly believe there would be some solution.

Comment: Is the tar file created?  Do you have enough disk space in the directory you are running the command in?  If you are low in space, you can add a `z` to `cfv` to compress the tar file.

Comment: Thanks. I am using a flash drive & have enough free disk space. I also tried adding 'z' & tar.gz.

Comment: @Kiron, but the way you have written your command in your original question, `tar` is trying to create the archive file 'user1.tar' in the **same**  directory as 'user1', meaning it on the same disk. Are you double-sure that you have enough disk space for the new archive file you are trying to create?

Answer (score 0):

I am glad to share the solutions which I found after various troubleshooting and with help of few google links.

1. We must avoid using -v and try 
   tar cf user1.tar --exclude 'user1/downloads' user1 > /dev/null

   It will then print the errors on stdout.  Otherwise in verbose mode it was waiting for few error messages and once it reaches certain number them displaying the final error message and exiting. After doing the above command with the stdout error messages I realized that I do not have enough permissions to certain file even after trying as a “root”.  Then I found the below second solutions.
2. By default terminal (on mac) doesn't have full disk access. So first we need to give full access to terminal
                Which can be done by selecting little apple logo on top left corner of the screen—> System Preferences —> Security & Privacy —> unlock the little Lock Icon on the bottom—>Privacy—> Hit little ‘+’ symbol—>Applications—>Utilities—>terminal
   Make sure it is added to the box.

That is it. Tar worked fine after performing above two steps. Hope this helps others